# How to return a String value to another class in regards to editText

Tags: java, android, crash, android-edittext, return

I am trying to display a textValue inserted by the user from the main class to another class/window.

On my main class I made this method

```
public String retChoice()
{
    choices[0] ="sasda"; //editText.getText().toString(); //pass from click button to method.
    choices[1] ="asdsa";//editText2.getText().toString(); 
    choices[2] = "asdsads";  //editText3.getText().toString();
    finalChoice =rand.nextInt(2);

    displayChoice = choices[finalChoice];

    return displayChoice; 
}
```

which works

but this

```
public String retChoice()
{
    choices[0] = editText.getText().toString(); //pass from click button to method.
    choices[1] = editText2.getText().toString(); 
    choices[2] = editText3.getText().toString();
    finalChoice =rand.nextInt(2);

    displayChoice = choices[finalChoice];

    return displayChoice; 
}
```

completely crashes the app.

Here's my other class of which I'm going to display the choice.

```
public class resultScreen extends Activity {



MainActivity ma = new MainActivity(); 
//Method supposedly retrieves the string data from MainActivity Class but somehow displayed null instead. 
//Find a way to keep the string variable when transfering from one class to another class. 
String finalResult = ma.retChoice(); 
 public void onCreate(Bundle resultScreen){
 super.onCreate(resultScreen);
 setContentView(R.layout.resultscreen);
  //ma.displayChoice.toString(); 

  String str = finalResult;

  TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  text.setText(str);
        }
```

Comment: Please do not repost just because you don't get the right answer. Try to make your original post better so people can help you. In your OP you were asked to provide logcat more than once. If you did that you would probably have an answer by now

Comment: Sorry lol , I'm new to this website. I should do that.

Comment: That's ok. See my answer on your original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access a view from another activity directly. You'll need to retrieve this value on another way, like using Singleton, extras or SharedPreferences.

The Android only keeps one activity rendered per time.

So, when you are trying to retrieve the EditText values on the MainActivity, these views are not created, so you'll get the null pointer exception.

Comment: Thanks Thiago. Now how would I approach this problem? Singleton seems like the way to go but I don't know where or how to start off.

Comment: Actually, i'm viewing your another thread and extras is your way to go. On your main activity, after creating the Intent, use `intent.putExtra("finalChoice", retChoice());` and on your resultScreen, instead of creating a mainactivity and retrieving the choices, use on your onCreate method: `resultScreen.getString("finalChoice")`

Comment: ops, `getIntent.getStringExtra("finalChoice");`

Comment: Alright , thanks Thiago ! Will do